# Flutter/Dart: getters with a parameter

Tags: flutter, dart

I can't understand how this works.
In the class:

```
Function(int) get myGet  {
  return myStream.sink.add;
}
```

and its implementation in a screen:

```
myObject.myGet(33);
```

and adds to the stream the number.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `myGet` you're actually calling `myStream.shink.add`.

```dart
void add(int a) {
  ...
}
```

and

```dart
Function(int) add = (int a) {
  ...
}
```

are same things.

Functions are a types too. Function names (eg: `myStream.shink.add`, `myObject.myGet`, `print`, ...) are pointer constants (since you can not assign another function to `print` on dart) pointing to address of the matching function on memory.

*PS: In javascript the predefined functions are like variables not constants since you can change default functions (eg: console.log) with your own handlers.*

When you call `print` compiler changes print with matching function address and when you call `print('Hello')` your arguments sent to that address. In your case the same thing happens too. But not on compile time, instead on runtime.

`myGet` is a getter returns type of function pointer. On runtime when you call `myGet` it returns address of `myStream.shink.add`. Adding parentheses after function calls it. Since you re calling `myGet` and it points to `myStream.shink.add` you're actually calling `myStream.shink.add(33)`.

Basically:

```dart
myObject.myGet = myStream.sink.add;
```

You can [read more about function pointers here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_(computer_programming)).

Comment: Thank you. By the way,  when or why could be necessary to use it?

Comment: @ROB for example you're declaring a button component. You need to call a function when the button is clicked. You also want to easily customize this function (write different functions for different buttons). For that case you will need to use function types. Flutter library uses Function types for lots of widgets: Inputs, Buttons, GestureDetector, ... .

Answer (score 1):

Why not just make a public function?

```
void add(int x) => myStream.sink.add(x);
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative option is using extensions so you can use `this` as a parameter

```
extension ContextExtension on BuildContext {
  double get sectionHorizontalPadding {
    final screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(this).size.width;
    return screenWidth > LandingDimensions.bodyMaxWidth
        ? (screenWidth - LandingDimensions.bodyMaxWidth) / 2
        : 0.0;
  }
}
```